# Replace specific columns content on browser refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, bootstrap-4

```js
$(".home").append($(".home .coco").sort(function () {
    return Math.random() - 0.5;
}));
```

```css
.row{margin-bottom: 30px;}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>


<div class="home">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3">A</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 coco">B</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">C</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">D</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3 coco">1</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">2</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 coco">3</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">4</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3">Red</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">Blue</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">Green</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 coco">Black</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Shuffle columns content randomly with other columns that have same class (coco). Now it's shuffle the content, but out of row. And remove the column from the row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method would work if the `.home` list contains only `.coco` items. It would mess up the list otherwise.

The idea here is to make a copy of the `.coco` items, sort them, and loop through the `.home` list and replace the `.coco` item one-by-one with the sorted `.coco` items.

```js
$(function() {
    let newArrangement = $(".home .coco").clone().sort(function() {
        return Math.random() - 0.5;
    });
    
    $('.home .coco').each(function(index) {       
        $(this).replaceWith(newArrangement[index]);
    });
});
```

The "making copy" part is important. If you don't do so, the newly replaced items might be replaced again.

#### Screenshot

[image]

#### Demo

https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/7pb5n8ut/50/